# Why is this autolayout specification not sufficient?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, constraints, autolayout

I am trying to get rid of those annoying warnings in Interface Builder, but I do not understand what it is complaining about (all Interface Builder, no code):

[image: Sceenshot from Xcode - Interface Builder]

I have specified a fixed with, fixed height and fixed distances to right and top.

Yet the warning tells me

```
Needs Constraints for: Y position, height
Needs Constraints for: X position, width
```

Can someone please explain how these are constraints are not sufficient?

**Edit**
Also, when using the "automatic" add constraints commands, it does nothing and the errors remain.

Comment: They certainly look sufficient. What version of iOS and Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using the newest version. If this is secret, I can continue the frustration of fruitless discussions over at the developer forum. But there should be an explanation in principle...

Comment: Seems like a bug -- these are still beta releases after all, but I don't get these warnings when I add similar constraints in iOS 7.

Comment: If it is the unmentionable version. Make sure you uncheck removes constraints at build time or something like that in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the superview is not pinned to a size in interface builder. Autolayout constraints seem to solve everything simultaneously and an error message that looks like it relates to one view can just as easily relate to the other view in the relationship.

What is `- (NSArray *)constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis` telling you?

Comment: Thanks for the debugging suggestion in code. I don't know if I even want to go there. Perhaps better wait until this has matured?